# Why is `robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL)` necessary?

Tags: java, junit4, awtrobot

When using Robot class, what is the meaning of:

```
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
```

Shouldn't the code below be sufficient to send the event?

```
Robot robot = new Robot();
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`keyPress` will send an event that a key has been pressed down.  `keyRelease` will send the event that the key has been released.  If you want to simulate typing, you might want to do something like:

```
public class SuperRobot extends Robot {
    public void typeKey(int keyCode) {
        keyPress(keyCode);
        delay(20);
        keyRelease(keyCode);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        SuperRobot r = new SuperRobot();
        // Now, let's press Ctrl+A
        r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
        r.typeKey(KeyEvent.VK_A);
        r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
    } catch (Exception ex) { // Either AWTException or SecurityException
        System.out.println("Oh no!");
    }
}
```

Note that to type something with a mask, like Ctrl+A, we first press down Ctrl, then simulate pressing and releasing A, then release Ctrl.  As a general rule, the robot should more-or-less exactly simulate what you as a user would do.

Comment: so if I want to send the event from my frame I can only do : Robot robot = new Robot();
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_P); ?

Comment: have I use release method ? or press is sufficient ?

Comment: It's just like a keyboard... press moves the key down, release moves the key up.  So it depends on what you want to test, but just imagine running the test in real life.  If you would press and hold the key, just use press.  If you would press and release (a.k.a. type) the key, you need to use both.  Honestly, just go play around with it... it's like 4 lines of code and it will be more edifying than my explanation.

Answer (score 0):

```
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
```

For Releasing the press effect on the key, If you have pressed a key using 
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
Then you should Release it too, otherwise once your java application runs, your keyboard has will continue with virtually CTRL key pressed.